K8s Readiness probe failed: success for ray-worker, docs maybe unclear
I’m working on setting up a Ray cluster with a head node and worker pods. While the head node deploys successfully and functions as expected, the worker node fails with the error: “Readiness probe failed: success.”
According to the Ray documentation, this error is expected if a Ray Serve application isn’t deployed. However, I don’t need Ray Serve, as my goal is simply to execute remote tasks and distribute them across the head and worker nodes.
How can I get the worker node to function correctly in this case? Should I override the health check to resolve this issue?
